# Finding Ro while designing an amplifier

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, homework

[image: image of the question text]

I didn't understand why we are subtracting load voltage from output open circuit voltage in part (c). What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-circuit voltage is the voltage at output when there is no load connected. So it will be same as the supply voltage at the output circuit. Now, a load \$ R_L\$ is connected and the output resistance\$R_o \$ is considered to be in series with it. So what should be the relationship between both the voltage drops? I guess that rings your bells now.

Comment: Thank you, it did!